# XAMPP, Mac OS X and linked files

Tags: javascript, html, macos, xampp

I'm sure the answer to this is obvious but:  I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and XAMPP on Mac OSX.  Someone sent me a web app so I could load it up but I'm running into the following issues:

1) While XAMPP intro pages loads up fine with just "localhost" using port 80, all my other projects will only load using 127.0.0.1:8020

2) Linked JS & CSS in the web app are written like this:

```
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

But I get 404; for Apache to find it I need to remove the first '/' so it looks like this:

```
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

I would like to understand what's happening here because I can't (don't think I should have to if I do it correctly) remove all the beginning '/' for the linked files.

Incidentally, I have set my server config to use a base URL and append project name.  The only thing that works is when I use 127.0.0.1:8020.  I've never had this happen on my Windows machine.

Comment: are you using a subfolder for your web app? Because "/js/controllers.js" means "localhost/js/controllers.js" for your browser

Comment: the web app came in deploy>public> and then all the actually css/js, etc.  I got ride of deploy and put public into htdocs and made it a project.  Perhaps I need to get rid of public folder and just put app directly into htdocs?

Comment: Right, if you want to keep the original "/js/foo.js" and "/css/foo.css" links, they have to be found in "htdocs/js/foo.js" and "/htdocs/css/foo.css". Browsers interpret links WITHOUT a slash at the beginning as "relative" (to the current folder) and WITH a slash at the start as "absolute" (to the current host). You can also use two slashes at the start, then only the protocol type (http, https, ...) will be kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some rest, I figured out that my problems were mostly because I'm not accustomed to working on a Mac but also being a bit sloppy.

I moved XAMPP out of Applications and into Documents while still leaving a copy of XAMPP in Applications and this was the root cause of my troubles.  The way Macs work (I guess), XAMPP would never work outside of Applications but having a copy in both places only compounded my problem.

What I probably could do is move htdocs into Documents while leaving the main XAMPP folder inside of Applications, making sure to change the document root for Apache in the appropriate conf files.

Regarding the absolute vs relative file paths for external files, the solution is to create another workspace in Aptana only for the web app.  Once again, Mac OSX doesn't want to cooperate: in Windows, you can launch multiple instances of Eclipse/Aptana to access different workspaces.  Not so with Mac and this has been a problem for roughly the past 6 years or more.  Luckily, someone created a plugin that remedies this problem very nicely and can be found here: http://bit.ly/MCPjQP  Works in both Eclipse and Aptana Studio 3

I hope someone else can benefit from this post.